# iOS: UITableview with sections and data insertion accordingly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am getting web service response like below:

```
 (
    {
    ChatDetailsID = 1;
    ChatID = 4;
    ChatLine = hI;
    Timestamp = "15-Jul-16 04:30";
    UserID = 2;
},
    {
    ChatDetailsID = 2;
    ChatID = 4;
    ChatLine = "hI!";
    Timestamp = "15-Jul-16 04:30";
    UserID = 6;
},
    {
    ChatDetailsID = 9;
    ChatID = 4;
    ChatLine = "sample string 3";
    Timestamp = "18-Jul-16 05:57";
    UserID = 2;
},
    {
    ChatDetailsID = 10;
    ChatID = 4;
    ChatLine = "sample string 4";
    Timestamp = "18-Jul-16 06:03";
    UserID = 2;
},
    {
    ChatDetailsID = 15;
    ChatID = 4;
    ChatLine = Dsjfrejfijrihfuirhgvurhuifhueirghiurhgvuirhiuvhriuhfiuerhihfrfreg;
    Timestamp = "19-Jul-16 01:11";
    UserID = 2;
}
)
```

and i want to show this data in table view but time stamp as table view section headers and data below that according to time stamp.

i am trying to do prepare dictionary with one key and multiple objects as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *temDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (int j = 0; j<[arrmDate count]; j++)
{
    for (int i =0; i< [arrmMsg count]; i++)
    {
        ChatContainer *object1 = [arrmMsg objectAtIndex:i];

         NSString * strobjdate = object1.strDate;
         NSString * strdate = [arrmDate objectAtIndex:j];

        if ([strdate isEqualToString:strobjdate])
        {
            [temDic setValue:object1.strChatLine forKey:strdate];
        }
    }
}
```

In above code arrmDate is date array containing distinct dates and arrmMsg contains output of container class where i stored all values i have got in web service response.

But i am getting only last values of that particular date as follows:

```
{
"15-Jul-16" = "hI!";
"18-Jul-16" = "sample string 4";
"19-Jul-16" = Dsjfrejfijrihfuirhgvurhuifhueirghiurhgvuirhiuvhriuhfiuerhihfrfreg;
}
```

i want as follows:

```
{
"15-Jul-16" = "hI","hI!";
"18-Jul-16" = "sample string 3","sample string 4";
"19-Jul-16" = Dsjfrejfijrihfuirhgvurhuifhueirghiurhgvuirhiuvhriuhfiuerhihfrfreg;
}
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong. or suggest any other solution for this.
Thank you.

Comment: Show the properties of chatcontainer

Comment: strDate what is the name?

Comment: ChatDetailsID ,
    ChatID ,
    ChatLine ,
    Timestamp ,
    UserID   these are the properties.

Comment: i have explained this in question itself.

Comment: You can't store or save same key .Dictionary keys are unique.

Comment: You can save using id here.Because it is unique above.

Comment: i want to show this data in table view with sections and sections are named date wise. so i want date as a key and its messages as multiple values if more than one.

Comment: Then directly use the armDate for setting tableView header.

Comment: Firstly, if you want to show the data on the table based on the date stamps, take an array of dictionaries. See, if the updated code, I provided comes to any help.

Comment: Bhagyashree mahajan check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

In Dictionary only one value can be stored for a particular key.
TimeStamp 15-Jul-16 04:30 occurs two times so second time value of this timeStamp(used as key) replaced with new Value.

Comment: we can store multiple values for one key as follows:

Comment: animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
                @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
                @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
                @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
                @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};

Comment: It has array for every key. but in your code you are storing single string object.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your first dictionary have `"15-Jul-16 04:30"` as Timestamp and the second dictionary also have `"15-Jul-16 04:30"` as Timestamp.

So, 1st time when the compiler encountered `[temDic setValue:object1.strChatLine forKey:strdate]` statement, it stored `"hI"` as there was no key in your dictionary containing `"15-Jul-16 04:30"`

Now, the 2nd time when it encountered the `[temDic setValue:object1.strChatLine forKey:strdate]` statement, there is already a key with `"15-Jul-16 04:30"`, so it just replaced that key with `"hI!"`

Now if you are just storing the date part in your `arrmdave` array, it can't obviously differentiate between the 3rd and 4th dictionary as for both of them the `striate` is `"18-Jul-16"`, so it went on replacing the same key again.

If you want to sort the dictionaries based on timestamp then firstly in your `arrmdave` array, keep the timeStamps along with the date and then take an array to hold the sorted dictionaries.

```
NSMutableDictionary *temDic;
NSMutableArray *sortedList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int j = 0; j<[arrmDate count]; j++)
{
    temDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *strdate = [arrmDate objectAtIndex:j];

    for (int i =0; i< [arrmMsg count]; i++)
    {
        ChatContainer *object1 = [arrmMsg objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *strobjdate = object1.strDate;

        if ([strdate isEqualToString:strobjdate])
        {
            [temDic setValue:object1.strChatLine forKey:strdate];
            [sortedList addObject: temDic];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure, your `arrmDate` holds the whole date string like `"15-Jul-16 04:30"` rather than `"15-Jul-16"`.

Comment: Response of above code is like this:(
 {
     "15-Jul-2016" = "hI!";
 },
 {
     "15-Jul-2016" = "hI!";
 },
 {
     "18-Jul-2016" = "sample string 4";
 },
 {
     "18-Jul-2016" = "sample string 4";
 },
 {
     "19-Jul-2016" = Dsjfrejfijrihfuirhgvurhuifhueirghiurhgvuirhiuvhriuhfiuerhihfrfreg;
 }
 )

Comment: I updated the code, please make sure, your arrmdave holds the entire date string, otherwise, my solution also won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am sorry for delay the answer.Yesterday at 8.30 pm when I posted answer it was - **Stack Overflow is currently offline** **for maintenance**.That is the reason only I could not post the answer yesterday.

Bhagyashree mahajan thank you.I tried to get the solution for 4 hours.Finally I got according to your output.I created array dictionary that how you have.My answer satisfy you.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSMutableDictionary *dict1,*dict2,*dict3,*dict4,*dict5,*dictResult;
  NSMutableArray *arrJsonResponse,*arrTimeStamp,*arrChatLine;
  NSMutableArray *arrAppendObject,*arrAppendKey;
  NSString *strAppendValue;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"ChatDetailsID",@"4",@"ChatID",@"hi",@"ChatLine",@"15-Jul-16 04:30",@"Timestamp",@"2",@"UserID", nil];
  dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"ChatDetailsID",@"4",@"ChatID",@"hi",@"ChatLine",@"15-Jul-16 04:30",@"Timestamp",@"6",@"UserID", nil];
  dict3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"9",@"ChatDetailsID",@"4",@"ChatID",@"sample string 3",@"ChatLine",@"18-Jul-16 05:57",@"Timestamp",@"2",@"UserID", nil];
  dict4 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"10",@"ChatDetailsID",@"4",@"ChatID",@"sample string 4",@"ChatLine",@"18-Jul-16 06:03",@"Timestamp",@"2",@"UserID", nil];
  dict5 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"15",@"ChatDetailsID",@"4",@"ChatID",@"Dsjfrejfijrihfuirhgvurhuifhueirghiurhgvuirhiuvhriuhfiuerhihfrfreg",@"ChatLine",@"19-Jul-16 01:11",@"Timestamp",@"2",@"UserID", nil];
  arrJsonResponse = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4,dict5,nil];


  arrTimeStamp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  arrChatLine = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  arrAppendObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  arrAppendKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  dictResult = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


   for(int i=0;i<arrJsonResponse.count;i++)
   {
      NSString *strTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrJsonResponse objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Timestamp"]];
      NSString *strChatLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrJsonResponse objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ChatLine"]];
      NSRange range = [strTimeStamp rangeOfString:@" "];
      strTimeStamp = [[strTimeStamp substringToIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
      NSLog(@"The date is - %@",strTimeStamp);
      [arrTimeStamp addObject:strTimeStamp];
      [arrChatLine addObject:strChatLine];
    }

   for(int j=0;j<arrTimeStamp.count;j++)
   {
      NSString *strDate = [arrTimeStamp objectAtIndex:j];
      NSString *strChatLine = [arrChatLine objectAtIndex:j];
      int index = (int)[arrTimeStamp indexOfObject:strDate];
      if(j != index)
      {
          [arrAppendKey removeLastObject];
          [arrAppendObject removeLastObject];
          strAppendValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[arrChatLine objectAtIndex:index],[arrChatLine objectAtIndex:j]];
          [arrAppendObject addObject:strAppendValue];
          [arrAppendKey addObject:strDate];
       }
       else
       {
          [arrAppendObject addObject:strChatLine];
          [arrAppendKey addObject:strDate];
       }
    }
    NSLog(@"The objects are - %@",arrAppendObject);
    NSLog(@"The keys are - %@",arrAppendKey);

   for (int k=0;k<arrAppendKey.count;k++)
   {
      NSString *strArrKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrAppendKey objectAtIndex:k]];
      NSString *strArrObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrAppendObject objectAtIndex:k]];
      [dictResult setObject:strArrObject forKey:strArrKey];
   }
   NSLog(@"The printed dictionary results are - %@",dictResult);
}
```

The Printed Results are

```
 The objects are -
 (
  "hi hi",
   "sample string 3 sample string 4",
   Dsjfrejfijrihfuirhgvurhuifhueirghiurhgvuirhiuvhriuhfiuerhihfrfreg
 )
 The keys are - 
 (
  "15-Jul-16",
  "18-Jul-16",
  "19-Jul-16"
 )

The printed dictionary results are - 
{
  "15-Jul-16" = "hi hi";
  "18-Jul-16" = "sample string 3 sample string 4";
  "19-Jul-16" = Dsjfrejfijrihfuirhgvurhuifhueirghiurhgvuirhiuvhriuhfiuerhihfrfreg;
}
```

Above code works perfectly.